# Ubuntu 12.04, can't find my home wifi network

Tags: 12.04, wireless, broadcom

I've tried several solutions I found on the web, but didn't manage to solve a problem.

Since today my laptop won't find my WiFi network, but neighbours' networks are suggested.
Another laptop with U12.04 does find one.

What do I do?

I've Dell Latitude-E4310,

```
02:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM4313 802.11bgn Wireless Network Adapter (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Dell Inspiron M5010 / XPS 8300
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 17
    Memory at f2c00000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: brcmsmac
    Kernel modules: bcma, brcmsmac
```

also

```
NetworkManager Tool
State: connected (global)
- Device: eth1 -----------------------------------------------------------------
  Type:              802.11 WiFi
  Driver:            wl
  State:             disconnected
  Default:           no
  HW Address:        1C:65:9D:7A:45:5C
  Capabilities:

  Wireless Properties
    WEP Encryption:  yes
    WPA Encryption:  yes
    WPA2 Encryption: yes
```

Should I provide anything else?
Many thanks in advance.

**UPD**: http://pastebin.com/NfzBK2HQ

Comment: It is safe to run it was written by me and some good friends it will help diagnose your wireless issue.
Paste this command in a terminal  `wget -N -t 5 -T 10 http://dl.dropbox.com/u/57264241/wireless_script && chmod +x wireless_script && ./wireless_script` 
It will download a script and create a file named (wireless-info.txt, or wireless-info.txt.tar.gz) in your home folder paste the contents of the file here http://pastebin.com/ then paste the link back here.  No internet then go to this link for running the script without internet.
[url]http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=12350385[/url]

Comment: @WildMan, done. http://pastebin.com/NfzBK2HQ

Comment: These answers are too complicated. If Ubuntu is trying to usurp the tyrants these answers must be something the masses can understand.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please do:

```
sudo apt-get purge bcmwl-kernel-source
sudo modprobe -rv wl
sudo modprobe -v brcmsmac
```

if there are any errors please continue with the commands then reboot. your wireless should be working now.

Comment: It seemed to me I've tried doing this. Well. I must have done too many modifications in sequence (not quite understanding what I was doing) :)

This worked. Awesome. You saved me, thank you!

Comment: Make sure it works after a reboot, we may have to unblacklist a driver or two.

Comment: Everything works perfectly. So a wrong driver was a problem?

Comment: Yes it was the wrong driver.

Comment: wow. thank you very much, man. this tip saved my life.

Comment: This solution works as well on 14.04.

Comment: I cannot view my wireless adapter anymore!