# Cannot find my home wifi connection with 14.04. Had a good wifi connection at work

Tags: wireless, 14.04, acer, connection, wireless-access-point

I spend most of last night on the forums trying to find a solution to no avail.

I have an acer aspire 5742z. I purged/removed/disabled the broadcom driver. I did an update, I updated the PCiids, non-freelinux firmware, black listed about anything people suggested I black listed etc...

The connection works on windows, I run dual-boot and I am able to see it amongst the other connections in my network window.

In Ubuntu it is simply not in my list. I tried connecting it to a hidden network, my home network uses wpa1 and that choice was not avaible, only wpa2. Don't know if that has anything to do with it. I copied all the information but through hidden it also didn't work.

Don't know what I am doing wrong, I just want this connection to show up in my list and connect to it. It theoretically should work, I am 2,5 meters away from the router, my microsoft os recognizes it and connects but Ubuntu doesn't.

Any help is appreciated,
Thanks.

Comment: I am having this same problem with an Aspire 5741.

Comment: Luckily, I found [a solution](http://askubuntu.com/a/369560/177437) in another thread.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ubuntu 12.04, can't find my home wifi network](http://askubuntu.com/questions/369223/ubuntu-12-04-cant-find-my-home-wifi-network)