# How do I get my Wireless connection to work again?

Tags: 12.04, networking, wireless, broadcom

{UPDATE: I re-activated the native device driver for my Broadcom Wireless adapter and changed my router settings to broadcast on Channel 5. This fixed the problem.}

My other computer is an Ubuntu (DELL) 12.04 laptop. I have messed up the wireless connections by mistake. Please help!!

Here's the background. My Ubuntu laptop was not able to detect my wireless network at home. All other devices (Android phones, Windows laptop, Macbook laptop) are able to detect the wireless network. I tried to solve this by searching for answers on Ask Ubuntu.

Unfortunately, my wireless stopped working completely after I tried this answer --> [Ubuntu 12.04, can't find my home wifi network](https://askubuntu.com/questions/369223/ubuntu-12-04-cant-find-my-home-wifi-network)

I successfully ran the first command "sudo apt-get purge bcmwl-kernel-source" which I understand removes my wireless configurations and purges any configuration files.

The second command "sudo modprobe -rv wl" resulted in a "FATAL: Module wl not found" message.

And now I cannot even see Wireless settings in my Network Settings window.

Comment: Please edit your question to add details of your wireless device from the terminal command: `lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A2` Welcome to askubuntu.

Comment: Please don't add "Closed" to your title.

Comment: Ok. Sorry. What should I do if my query is resolved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand, you removed (purged) the Broadcom wireless drivers.
They are needed to use the Broadcom WLAN module of your DELL PC.

Reinstall the drivers and reboot your computer.

```
sudo apt-get install bcmwl-kernel-source  
sudo reboot
```

In case you have a Broadcom wireless card which needs another driver
(it isn't visible from the information provided in your question above) :

Identify your Broadcom wireless card

```
lspci -vvnn | grep Network
```

and search for the correct driver [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/Driver/bcm43xx).